# Tirar borda da pagina

Tags: css

Olá, gostaria de saber como posso tirar as bordas que ficaram entre a pagina e o background..  Gostaria de deixar a content completa  --- Não Negative se não pode ajudar ... A pergunta é basica que fiz.

[image: Gostaria de retirar essa sobra azul]

O codigo da wrapper esta assim

```
.responsive .inner { max-width:1310px; background: #e2e2e2; width:auto; margin:0 auto; }
```

Gostaria de retirar essa sobra verde

Sobre o codigo da main

```
.wrapper { padding: 0; min-width:1310px; background: #fff; margin:0 auto; }
.boxed-layout .wrapper  { width:1310px; background: #FFF; margin:0 auto; }
.inner { width:1280px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; /* main width */ }
.responsive .inner { max-width:1280px; border: 0; background: #e2e2e2; width:auto;}
body.responsive.isMobile .wrapper { overflow:hidden; }
```

Quando eu coloco em boxed o site fica sem borda mas preciso utilizar a `.responsive .inner`

Resolvido , coloquei em modo boxed e configurei o codigo dele
.boxed-layout .bg-shadow { max-width:1280px; width:auto; margin:0 auto; 
Agraço desde já . Obrigado

Comment: Luã, para remover a borda basta colocar no CSS do elemento `border: 0;` ou remover as propriedades de borda que estiverem no CSS, porém precisamos do código HTML e do CSS para poder te ajudar pois não é possível identificar qual é o elemento apenas por essa imagem nem se realmente é uma borda, isso também pode ser o `background` de outro elemento...

Comment: Eu to vendo um verde, e não azul rs

Answer (score 1):

Olá, basta colocar o `border: none;`

Comment: Perfeito, muito Obrigado